# My Markers won't show on Google Map in Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular10

I am trying to use the Google Maps component which is now part of material. I was able to get the map showing and trigger the events when clicking etc. but for some reason, I have no luck showing a marker on my map.

My HTML Code looks like this, I can see there is a value in Markers as I print it on button of the page. So I am not sure what I am missing here or what's wrong.

```
<google-map
  height="500px"
  width="100%"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [center]="center"
  [options]="options"
  (mapClick)="click($event)"
>
  <map-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of markers"
    [position]="marker.position"
    [label]="marker.label"
    [title]="marker.title"
    [options]="marker.options"
  >
  </map-marker>
</google-map>

{{markers | json}}
```

My TS code looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap } from '@angular/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){
  }
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap;

  title = 'ag-google-map';
  markers = [];
  zoom = 12;
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    // maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom: 8,

  };

  addMarker() {
    this.markers.push({
      position: {
        lat: 35.5362475,
        lng: -117.9267386,
      },
      label: {
        color: 'red',
        text: 'Marker label ' + (this.markers.length + 1),
      },
      title: 'Marker title ' + (this.markers.length + 1),
      options: { animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE },
    });
  }


  click(event: google.maps.MouseEvent) {
  console.log(event);
  this.logCenter();
}

  ngOnInit() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.center = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude,
    };
  });
  this.addMarker();

}

  logCenter() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.map.getCenter()));
}
```

Comment: What is `center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral;`? You are supposed to provide coords for the map center. Did you confirm your map is centered on your marker? In any case, you must provide a [mcve] along with debugging details and what you have tried to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your geo location (map center) is far from the marker point. So you can't see it in your viewing area of map. So only you are not able to see the marker.

to test that I changed the map center position to marker location then I can see the marker in map.

```
 ngOnInit() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.center = {
      lat: 35.5362475,
      lng: -117.9267386,
    };
  });
  console.log(this.center);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.addMarker();
  }, 1000)


}
```

[image]